# GC logs - VM operation events - how to track them

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I'm using GCViewer to check some GC logs. ( please check the screenshot below)

Im getting lots of high pauses (red rectangles) which seem to be related to "vm operation events(application stopped...)". These seem to be different from regular and full GC Stops .

- How can I get to know which are the operations which are triggering a stop event? (Is there a JVM flag for this?)
- Are they different from garbage collection? as far as GCViewer goes the Full GC Pauses + GC Pauses != Total Pause

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `-XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics –XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1` will give information about the operations that are triggering a stop event.

From: [this link](http://blog.ragozin.info/2012/10/safepoints-in-hotspot-jvm.html)

> **When safepoints are used?**
>
> Below are few reasons for HotSpot JVM to initiate a safepoint:
>
> - Garbage collection pauses
> - Code deoptimization
> - Flushing code cache
> - Class redefinition (e.g. hot swap or instrumentation)
> - Biased lock revocation
> - Various debug operation (e.g. deadlock check or stacktrace dump)

For writing the logs to a file, it depends which VM version you are using.

**For all Java versions:** [Java 8 Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).

> **-Xloggc:filename**
>
> Sets the file to which verbose GC events information should be redirected for logging. The information written to this file is similar to the output of `-verbose:gc` with the time elapsed since the first GC event preceding each logged event. The `-Xloggc` option overrides `-verbose:gc` if both are given with the same `java` command.

**From Java version 8:**

> **-XX:LogFile=path**
>
> Sets the path and file name where log data is written. By default, the file is created in the current working directory, and it is named `hotspot.log`.

Comment: he probably already has those flags, otherwise the logs would not contain VM operation overhead times in the first place

Comment: The screenshot posted in the question only shows the stopped times, not why they were stopped, right? The flags that I mentioned should give more details than that. Also the posts I linked to give some background information about activity of the VM.

Comment: no, `PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime` only prints the amount of time, not the reasons / additonal details, which is probably how GCViewer got the information in the first place. See my answer for the flags that give additional information. Those are also mentioned in the post you linked, but not in your answer.

Comment: You are right, I was mistaken. Thanks for pointing that out. I corrected my answer.

Comment: well detailed explanation. I got no idea of safepoints before, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add `-XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics –XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1` to your VM options, that should add information about non-GC safepoints to the logs.

`-XX:LogFile=/path/to/file -XX:+LogVMOutput` for logging to a file.

Comment: will these info be logged in gc.logs? or is there a flag for routing these logs to an specific file?

Comment: @DavidPrzybilla no I believe that they go to standard out by default